# Outlook shows all the email read yesterday as unread

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, pop3

The customer goes to another office several times a month and when she comes back to the main office, Outlook shows all the messages that she read while out of the office as unread again. This is on a POP account. She is not getting duplicate messages. The messages are just showing up as unread.

Outlook 2013

EDIT: To clarify, this is all happening on the same laptop. There is no exchange server. The account has to remain POP because they have small mailboxes that overflow with IMAP.

Comment: At the main office, how is POP configured? Does it download from the server and erase from the server? How about satellite office? Does it download and erase as well? My guess would be that the satellite office is not set to erase after download. So, when the main office downloads the e-mail, it is marked as unread because at the main office that e-mail was never read. Server doesn't know it was read before because POP3 isn't smart enough to know mails were read. You want to use IMAP or a different way to talk to the mail server.

Comment: Idea: Right click the Mail box - Properties - Advanced - Advanced tab - Check the checkboxes in `cached exchange mode settings`